# Why do all my entry boxes edit when I am only typing in one using tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, widget

I know there was a similar question, but I don't think the answer was applicable to my code and I would like to know the answer. Certain aspects of my program will not work because of this problem. This is my code:

```
from tkinter import *

def Add():
    num = entry_box.get()
    num1 = entry_box1.get()
    total = int(num) + int(num1)
    button["bg"] = "blue"
    button["fg"] = "white"
    entry_box.delete(0, END)
    entry_box1.delete(0, END)
    entry_box1.insert(0,total)

def Reset():
    button1["bg"] = "blue"
    button1["fg"] = "white"
    entry_box.delete(0, END)
    entry_box1.delete(0, END)

window = Tk()
window.geometry("200x150")

label = Message(text = "Enter the number you would like to add to the total: ")
label.pack()

entry_box = Entry(text = 0)
entry_box.pack()

num = entry_box.get()

entry_box1 = Entry(text = "0")
entry_box1.insert(0,"0")
entry_box1.pack()

num1 = entry_box.get()

button = Button(text = "Add", command = Add)
button.pack()

button1 = Button(text = "Reset", command = Reset)
button1.pack()

window.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is the `text` parameter of the `Entry` widget that is causing the issue.
As far as I know, there is no such parameter for the `Entry` widget.
So getting rid of `text` parameter will make your program run as expected.

```py
entry_box = Entry(text = 0)
entry_box1 = Entry(text = "0")

# to simply

entry_box = Entry()
entry_box1 = Entry()
```

Comment: tkinter widgets allow you to abbreviate option names. So, `text` is the same as `textvariable`.

Comment: @BryanOakley That makes sense.

Comment: @BryanOakley That's actually why I didn't understand the answer to the question similar to this one.